# Unable to set datasource in VS2010 for reporting service

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

[image]
I was unable to make datasource connection in Visual Studio 2010 for reports. I've already tried refresh many times but still, the list of server name is empty.
How could I solve this issue?

Reporting Service Configuration Manager in my machine is working fine. 
I have installed SQL server express advanced and using Visual Studio 2012.

Comment: The error occurred because I didn't turn on SQL browser Agent.

Comment: You can also just type a server name into that box if the browse feature isn't working.